# Read captcha image from site registration form to show it on my java program's form version

Tags: java, forms, web-crawler, captcha

I developed a site with a registration form and this form uses a captcha. Now I'm developing a Java desktop application that make possible for an user to register my site through the application. The application should present a registration form with same fields of the site, and for this I have no problem. But the site need a captcha, so I would like to show the captcha sent from site on my desktop application. If I use a crawler like JSoup I need to re-download the captcha image, and my captcha system on site changes the image at every request. In this way captcha image will always be incorrect.
The idea to create a different, captcha free, registration request to the site is a bad choice. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to send cookies

Comment: Cookie's values acting like nonce you mean?

Comment: No.  If you send cookies (or the CAPTCHA's hidden field), the CAPTCHA will work correctly from JSoup.

Comment: Sending a cookie from my site that can be read from captcha module on server when submitting the form, requesting the image I need to server? In this way I'll do 2 requests, one for the whole form and another for the captcha image using the value of the cookie. Do I understand?

Comment: Yes. (assuming your CAPTCHA works that way)

Comment: Thanks! I modified captcha behavior, now it runs.